STM32 Nucleo F303RE: USART1 DMA not receiving data from GY-25 sensor
I'm working on a project with the STM32 Nucleo F303RE, and I'm using USART1 to receive data from a GY-25 sensor at 9600 bps using DMA. However, I'm not receiving any data through the DMA callback. I’ve verified that the GY-25 is transmitting data, but my HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback is never triggered, and the rxBuffer remains empty. I am using USART2 to communicate with termite.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE 8

uint8_t rxBuffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
float Elevation, Azimuth;
uint8_t imu_updated = 0;

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
    if (rxBuffer[0] == 0xAA && rxBuffer[7] == 0x55) {
        Azimuth = (int16_t)((rxBuffer[1] << 8) | rxBuffer[2]) / 100.0f;
        Elevation = (int16_t)((rxBuffer[3] << 8) | rxBuffer[4]) / 100.0f;
        imu_updated = 1;
    }
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, rxBuffer, RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
}

int main(void) {
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    
    // Start UART reception using DMA
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, rxBuffer, RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    
    while (1) {
        if (imu_updated) {
            imu_updated = 0;
            // Process azimuth and elevation
        }
        HAL_Delay(100);
    }
}

USART 1 initialization:
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void) {
    huart1.Instance = USART1;
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

DMA Configuration:
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) {
    __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
    
    /* DMA interrupt init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn);
}

Full main.c:
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "math.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f3xx_hal_uart.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE 8

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_rx;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
//GY25 variables
uint8_t rxBuffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE]={0};

float Elevation, Azimuth;

uint8_t imu_updated = 0;

//debug variables
char message[50];  // Buffer to hold the message
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void send_debug_message(const char *message);
//void getAzEli(void);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

void send_debug_message(const char *message)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)message, strlen(message), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart){
     if (rxBuffer[0] == 0xAA && rxBuffer[7] == 0x55)
     {
         Azimuth = (int16_t)((rxBuffer[1] << 8) | rxBuffer[2]) / 100.0f;
         Elevation = (int16_t)((rxBuffer[3] << 8) | rxBuffer[4]) / 100.0f;
         imu_updated = 1;
     }
     HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, rxBuffer, RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
     __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_IDLE);
}




/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

//  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
//  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3);

  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, rxBuffer, RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
  __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_IDLE);
  send_debug_message("Stabilizing...\n");

  HAL_Delay(3000);  // Wait 3 seconds for GY-25 to stabilize
  send_debug_message("Calibrating...\n");

  //GY25 setup
  uint8_t zero_both_axis_cmd[] = {0xA5, 0x54};  // Pitch and roll correction
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, zero_both_axis_cmd, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_Delay(4000);  // Wait for calibration

  uint8_t auto_mode_cmd[] = {0xA5, 0x52};  // Set automatic mode
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, auto_mode_cmd, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  send_debug_message("Calibration complete!\n");

  // Start UART reception using DMA


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
//PWM CODE
      //forwards
//      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1, 30); // 10% duty cycle
//      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 0);


//      HAL_Delay(10000);
//      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1, 50); // 50% duty cycle
//      HAL_Delay(10000);
//      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_1, 100); // 100% duty cycle
//      HAL_Delay(10000);

        //backwards
//      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 10); // 50% duty cycle
//      HAL_Delay(10000);
//      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 50); // 50% duty cycle
//      HAL_Delay(10000);
//      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 100); // 50% duty cycle
//      HAL_Delay(10000);
//

//END PWM

        //GY 25 Code
            if (imu_updated)
            {
              imu_updated = 0;
              snprintf(message, sizeof(message), "Azimuth: %.2f, Elevation: %.2f \n", Azimuth, Elevation);
              send_debug_message(message);

            }
            HAL_Delay(100);  // Adjust delay as needed

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PREDIV = RCC_PREDIV_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1|RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2
                              |RCC_PERIPHCLK_TIM2|RCC_PERIPHCLK_TIM34;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInit.Tim2ClockSelection = RCC_TIM2CLK_HCLK;
  PeriphClkInit.Tim34ClockSelection = RCC_TIM34CLK_HCLK;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 71;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 99;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 1 */
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 71;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 99;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


Do you think that your DMA init function is sufficient?

@0___________ I believe so, it has worked for me before. And this is how a tutorial on YouTube did it

I would suggest to use Reference Manual instead of youtube tutorials

@0___________ The init function is also auto-generated, and all the DMA settings are configured as needed in the .ioc file

Then ask STM support as they wrote HAL libraries

It does not look like the dma is enabled/setup for you uart ..

where did you declare the DMA handle structure DMA_HandleTypeDef ?

@Geisterfahrer It is auto generated under the private variables banner in full main.c

I believe it is missing the initialization of the DMA handle structure hdma_usart1_rx, take a look in the example below:
void HAL_USART_MspInit(USART_HandleTypeDef *husart)
{
    // Configure these USART pins as alternate function pull-up
    /* Your Configuration */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_MspInit 1 */
    /* USART1 DMA Init */
    hdma_usart1_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel5;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;

    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart1_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE END USART2_MspInit 1 */
}

As you are using the HAL library, I recommend you reading in the file stm32f3xx_hal_usart.c the explanation how to use USART HAL Driver.
